# Speed up code to run through plist

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, plist

I'm running through a plist with 4000 words. My code works but it takes a few seconds to run the code. Is there anyway to speed up my code to run through the plist?

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myList" ofType:@"plist"];
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
for (NSString *str in array) {
NSLog(@"%@", str);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Store the words in a sqlite3 database instead.

Comment: @Droppy that is unlikely got help.

Comment: Oh well, ask a silly question...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NSLog() is slow.  Remove that and just do the work, it'll be faster.

Here's a test comparison of printing each line versus making a new string by appending to the existing string.

```
   // create test array
   NSMutableArray * strings = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4000; i++)
    {
        [strings addObject:@"new string"];
    }

    // create variables for storing test time. 
    CFTimeInterval startTime, endTime;

    // test the NSLog loop
    startTime = CACurrentMediaTime();
    for (NSString * string in strings) {
        NSLog(@"%@", string);
    }
    endTime = CACurrentMediaTime();
    NSLog(@"Total Runtime for NSLog: %g s", endTime - startTime);

    // test the comparison loop
    startTime = CACurrentMediaTime();
    for (NSString * string in strings) {
        NSString* newString = [string stringByAppendingString:@"   "];
    }
    endTime = CACurrentMediaTime();
    NSLog(@"Total Runtime for appending: %g s", endTime - startTime);
```

On my iPhone 6 :

Total Runtime for NSLog: 0.55105 s

Total Runtime for appending: 0.00366363 s

The timing test code was modified from this excellent NSHipster article:
http://nshipster.com/benchmarking/

Comment: To compare this code the actual result from the appending string method needs to be printed before endTime is captured. Otherwise printing to output is slower than memory management of characters only.